# How to apply For Loop to create Multiple PIVOT Tables using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, pivot-table

I want to create 14 pivot table.I have recorded a macro.My macro code is given below.If I want to apply for loop to create 14 pivot tables, how to do that?

I am a beginner so unable to understand how to apply for loop to automate this recorded code?

My macro is given below:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Current Fleet Comparison!R1C1:R1048576C41", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("AircraftType")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("AircraftType"), "Count of AircraftType", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("OperatorArea")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Range("A1:F5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "A318"
    Range("A15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "A319"
    Range("A22").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "A320"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Range("A29").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "A321"
    Range("A36").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "ATR 42"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Range("A43").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "ATR 72"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("A50").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "CRJ100 Regional Jet"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    Range("A57").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("AircraftType").CurrentPage _
        = "CRJ200 Regional Jet"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("A65").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        CurrentPage = "Q100"
    Range("A72").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable11").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        CurrentPage = "Q200"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("A79").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable12").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        CurrentPage = "Q300"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("A86").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable13").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        CurrentPage = "Q400"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("A94").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable14").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable14").PivotFields("AircraftType"). _
        CurrentPage = "Q400 NextGen"
End Sub
```

I am a beginner so unable to understand how to apply for loop to automate this recorded code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following macro, since your sample code didn't contain all 14 pages to be used for the pagefield, you'll need to complete the list being assigned to varPages before running the macro...

```
'Force the explicit declaration of variables
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePivotTables()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim varPages As Variant
    Dim objPivotCache As PivotCache
    Dim objPivotTable As PivotTable
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim CurrRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'Turn off screen updating to speed up macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assign the source worksheet for the pivottables to wksSource
    Set wksSource = Worksheets("Current Fleet Comparison")

    'Assign the source range for the pivottables to rngSource
    Set rngSource = wksSource.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    'Create the pivotcache for the pivottables
    Set objPivotCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=rngSource)

    'Add new worksheet for the pivottables
    Sheets.Add

    'Assign the list of pages for the pagefield to varPages (add the remaining pages)
    varPages = Array("A318", "A319", "A320", . . .)

    CurrRow = 3
    For i = 1 To 14
        'Create the pivottable
        Set objPivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add( _
            PivotCache:=objPivotCache, _
            TableDestination:=Cells(CurrRow, "A"), _
            TableName:="PivotTable" & i)
        'Add the fields for the pivottable
        With objPivotTable
            .AddDataField .PivotFields("AircraftType"), "Count of AircraftType", xlCount
            .PivotFields("OperatorArea").Orientation = xlColumnField
            With .PivotFields("AircraftType")
                .Orientation = xlPageField
                .CurrentPage = varPages(i - 1)
            End With
            With .TableRange2
                CurrRow = .Offset(.Rows.Count + 4).Row
            End With
        End With
    Next i

    'Show the pivottable field list
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

    'Turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```